# Is there a review article that discusses the various suggestions for approaches to the Dirac spinor field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, spinors

I've come across many approaches to the Dirac spinor field over the years. A few have held more than passing interest but most of them are rather forgettable, so that *I'd like to know of any reviews that gather together a good collection of the various approaches that are out there*. Just picking examples that come immediately to mind, [Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716703440) have interesting things to say, for example, and so do [Penrose and Rindler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521337070). There is some of the literature on Clifford algebras that is interesting, including, perhaps, [Lounesto](http://users.tkk.fi/ppuska/mirror/Lounesto/)'s [Clifford Algebras and Spinors (London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521599164), although in that mathematics one has to be fairly selective (Lounesto's web-page points to a particular individual's selection).

I'm more interested in citable reviews of approaches that are grounded in solid mathematics, but favorite reviews of relatively wild interpretations will also be welcome. Approaches that take the adventurous step of considering the impact of quantization and fermionic algebraic structure will be particularly welcome, although my fairly strong perception is that perhaps the only solid approach to quantized Dirac spinor fields is shut up and calculate the S-matrix?

A look through the Wikipedia pages that are linked to from the [Spinor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) page gave me no links to reviews, similarly [nCatLab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/HomePage) and [Am.J.Phys.](http://ajp.aapt.org/).

Comment: Hm... I'll certainly let you know if I find anything, but that seems like a pretty broad topic. I could easily imagine a review article actually turning into a textbook. (Which I guess isn't saying much, because people do publish 100+ page papers on arXiv...) Good question though.

Comment: Found something that's approximately what I wanted, "Algebraic and Dirac–Hestenes spinors and spinor fields", Waldyr A. Rodrigues, J. Math. Phys. 45, 2908 (2004); http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1757037
I would have preferred something that wasn't so Hestenes, but it's a review article that does include many of the references I knew of into other literature.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly comprehensive book by Thaller, called ''The Dirac equation'',
published 1992, which discusses a spinor particle from many angles.

Possibly, the book can be downloaded from one of the links at 
http://ebookee.org/Thaller-The-Dirac-Equation_141995.html